# How do I use importxml to pull a still/cover photo from an instagram photo?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, social-media

I'm creating a report on social media performance. I have the link to the post in a cell and I'm using importxml to pull the photo/video so people know which post i'm referencing. Here's the formula I'm using:

```
=IMAGE(IMPORTXML(D63,"//meta[@property='og:image']/@content"))
```

However, the image is cut in half on the instagram posts - but looks great on the tiktok posts. I can't figure out what the xpath should be instead after experimenting with inspecting element on instagram & playing around with different xpaths. Hoping someone here might have an answer!

I get a a photo that's cut half way, almost as if it didn't finish loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach:*

```js
=image(substitute(A2,"reel","p")&"media/?size=l")
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh it works for photos, but I realize that some things are reels and it's not working for those posts. Thank you for this possible solution - i'll keep it in mind for the photos specifically.

Comment: can you maybe share one such url to test...

Comment: absolutely - here's one https://www.instagram.com/reel/CteF5y9NhRV/ and https://www.instagram.com/p/CttnY4cupgp/

Comment: Can you try the updated answer

Comment: YOU ARE MAGICAL!!! That worked!!!! I'll write a formula that looks for "reel" in the text and if it's a real, it will use that. Thank you so much. I was going nuts trying to figure out the answer!